# What's an efficient way of maintaining a list of dirty objects or indexes when you have 100k to a Million objects/indexes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to iterate over +100k objects in real-time (for a video game).

To make things faster, I implemented a `HashSet<int> DirtyIndexes` and whenever an object is modified, I do `DirtyIndexes.Add(index)` and iterate over those indexes only.

Unfortunately `HashSet.Add()`'s duplicate check is kinda slow and, at 10k+ objects per frame, the process of adding that many indexes kills any advantage of using this system.

I was hoping to find a collection that allowed multiple objects to share a key and would return an array of everything that matches the search key, but couldn't find anything.

Another idea is to use an int array of the same size as the number of objects and set 0 for clean, 1 for dirty, but then I have to add several Ifs to my code to filter out indexes, which would also slow things down.

I could also add the dirty objects to a DirtyObject list, but then I once again have to prevent duplicates and end up with the same problem.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: You have to iterate over 100k+ objects _every frame_?

Comment: for the problem to be clear its necessary to show some code

Comment: @SpencerBench I'm trying to avoid iterating over all of them by implementing a dirty list, so I can only process those objects that were changed every frame.

Comment: @TCZ8 See my answer for a potential solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys made excellent suggestions, but running with this many entities, I had to come up with something else.

The secret is to use 2 arrays. One for the value and the second one for its dirty flag (0 or 1). This prevents duplicates (doesn't matter if the value is set dirty multiple times) and is much faster. Both arrays are initialized ahead of time to my pool size.

The idea is to use a set of array like this for every value I want to iterate through. Doing it this way allows processing the data at different rates while maintaining compatibility with Unity's Job system.

Burst is amazing, Vectorization, you are next!

EDIT: To clarify, I sort the dirty list on render (where I already have to iterate on everything) and process the dirty data on the next frame. The 1 frame latency in processing allows planning the work ahead of time and isn't detectable in game.

Comment: If you guys don't agree with my answer, let me know.

Comment: Could you add a code (or pseudo-code) example to explain your point ?

Comment: So If I understand well, 1/ You change you goal, since now with your 1/0 flag you are not *iterating only on dirty objects* anymore. 2/ What is different from storing your 1/0 flag as a property of your object ?

Comment: Hi XouDo, you're right. I had to change how I process things. I tested the other solution I mentioned, and it worked out. In my case, it's faster than Spencer's suggestion because I take advantage of already iterating on all entities on render to sort the dirty list. This way I need only 1 check per entity for the dirty system. Of course, I have to delay processing 1 frame now. I guess I forgot to mention it. The more I dig in high performance processing, the more I realize the importance of sorting and planning the work to be done ahead of time, especially if planning to use vectorization.

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question: I use the job system for processing and Jobs can only contain blittable types which means I can't use custom classes. I could use a struct, but to get the best speed and to benefit from vectorization I need my data to be lined up in a row in memory. Vectorization is a complex subject, I just know that doing it this way works. There are crazy things you can do with pointers but I'm not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency its better to use an array than a list. If you want to use the features of the `List` class but to use the array when needed, you can use a class that has an array and a list as class variables, and update the array only when the list is changed, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CustomList<T>
{
    //private
    bool _isDirty;
    List<T> _list;
    T[] _array;

    //public
    T[] getArray() {
        if (_isDirty)
            _array = _list.ToArray();
        return _array;
    }

    //handler methods
    public CustomList() {
        _list = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T item) {
        _list.Add(item);
        _isDirty = true;
    }

    public void Remove(T item) {
        _list.Remove(item);
        _isDirty = true;
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int i) {
        _list.RemoveAt(i);
        _isDirty = true;
    }

    public bool Contains(T item) {
        return _list.Contains(item);
    }

    public int Count() {
        return _list.Count;
    }

    public T this[int index] {
        get { return _list[index]; }
        set { _list[index] = value; }
    }

    public void Clear() {
        _list.Clear();
        _isDirty = true;
    }

    public void RemoveAll(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        _list.RemoveAll(predicate);
        _isDirty = true;
    }

    public T Find(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        return _list.Find(predicate);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item) {
        _list.Insert(index, item);
        _isDirty = true;
    }

    public void ForEach(Action<T> action) {
        _list.ForEach(action);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like this, but I need it to prevent duplicates index from being added and return an array containing only the dirty indexes.

Comment: you can check if the index is already in before adding it, or code the logic to remove the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use a `List<int>` for `DirtyObjects`, since `List<T>` is essentially just an array with quality of life features on top of it, and you can iterate over it very quickly.

As for preventing duplicates, you could maintain a `bool isDirty` flag in each object and only add an object to the list if its flag isn't already set:

```
private void OnChanged() {
    if (!this.isDirty) {
        this.isDirty = true;
        DirtyObjects.Add(this.index);
    }
}
```

This would prevent any object from being added to `DirtyObjects` more than once. (And it doesn't have to do any kind of lookup in the process!) This logic also doesn't need to be particularly fast, since it's only executed whenever a clean object becomes dirty.

Then whatever code eventually "cleans up" the dirty objects can set their `isDirty` flags back to `false`, and the cycle continues.